# My layout doesn't show on my MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

My activity_main.xml doesn't start when I run my app with the emulator. I'm using Android Studio. Everytime I run my app, the layout is completely white...

Here's my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Here's my activity_main.xml:

```xml
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <Button
        android:background="@color/button"
        android:id="@+id/start_workout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Start workout"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/start_workout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <Button
            android:background="@color/button"
            android:id="@+id/cardio_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cardio"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" />

        <Button
            android:background="@color/button"
            android:id="@+id/log_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Build Workout"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:onClick="buildWorkout"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout">

        <Button
            android:background="@color/button"
            android:id="@+id/progress_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Progress"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" />

        <Button
            android:background="@color/button"
            android:id="@+id/calendar_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Calendar"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I wonder why Eclipse didn't catch that when it compiled the XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not closing your relative layout in your xml. Put `</RelativeLayout>` at the end of your xml

Answer (score 0):

Well from what i can see you've got a relative layout that is never closed fix that... and what's up with your mainactivity.java there's nothing in it except the default stuff... well hald of the default stuff....

Comment: He probably hasn't implemented anything else yet because his layout wasn't displaying. Don't be so critical.

Comment: okey dokey well i am trying to get votes so i can get unbanned from asking questions so please thumbs it up pleasee! xD